# ASP.NET Webmail Engine

Tags: asp.net

A friend of mine asked me today if there is any open-source or commercially available Webmail/Email "engine". When I asked her what she meant by engine, I got a list of features her boss asked for -

- Web interface to login & access e-mails
- Ability to send/receive/forward e-mails using the web interface
- Ability to compose and save drafts using the web interface
- Ability to delete emails, empty deleted items folder using the web interface
- Ability to search e-mails (by Sender's e-mail, Subject, Content)
- Maintain and manage a contacts list (of e-mail addresses) using the web interface
- Allow users to synchronise their e-mails with iPhone/Windows Mobile smartphones

I found [SharpWebMail](http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpwebmail/) to have some of the features, although it has not had updates in recent times, last update was in April 2006. I am inclined towards using ASP.NET, the proposal is to primarily use the e-mail in conjunction with an intranet (developed in ASP.NET). If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

indy

Answer (score 1):

There is

- gmail [http:/www.google.com/mail](http://www.google.com/mail)
- Outlook Exchange with Webmail http://www.microsoft.com/EXCHANGE/default.mspx
- Yahoo mail etc
- [http://www.eudora.com/](http://www.eudora.com)
- http://www.bynari.net/products/server/products.html
- [http://atmail.com/](http://atmail.com)

try google "mail server with web client" or similar

Comment: Thanks for the links. The management wishes to have their employees using their "branded" e-mail! So, using any free services are ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use gmail apps for the web portion: http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html

Excellent web interface, and you can have addresses of the form user.name@yourdomain.com (not just @gmail.com)

It has mobile support and also allows the use of other clients using pop or imap if you need to use desktop software for synching etc.